# How can i make a list of directories from two list nested (parent and child)

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a parent-list of two elements

```
P= ["E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin" , "E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure"]
```

but first element has another list:

```
Cld1 = ['BGD_4_new_district', 'BGD_3_old_district', 'BGD_2_division', 'BGD_1_all', 'BGD_5_Upazilla', 'BGD_4_old_district', 'BGD_6_Union_court', 'BGD_6_Union', 'BD_exposed_coastal_area','BD_drought', 'BGD_1_River', 'BGD_1_River_detail', 'BD_international_bnd', 'BGD_1_River_1', 'BGD_7_Mauza', 'test', 'BGD_5_UpazillaAnno', 'BGD_4_new_districtAnno', 'BGD_4_new_districtAnno2']
```

and second element has another list:

```
Cld2 = ['BD_Health_Infrastructures_1', 'BD_Railway_Establishments_1', 'BGD_roads_1']
```

Now i want to join P and (Cld1 and Cld2) i.e. P+Cld1  and P+Cld2 to  make os path and it (P+Cld1  and P+Cld2) will be saved in an array "My_Full_Path"  e.g "E:\GIS_DOCUMENT\BCAS_Map\BCAS_All.gdb\BD_Admin   \  BGD_4_new_district" is an element of "My_Full_Path" list

How to do

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem  correctly then I guess you need this:

```
import os
import pprint
P= ["E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin" , "E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BCAS_BD_Infrastructure"]
Cld1 = ['BGD_4_new_district', 'BGD_3_old_district', 'BGD_2_division', 'BGD_1_all', 'BGD_5_Upazilla', 'BGD_4_old_district', 'BGD_6_Union_court', 'BGD_6_Union', 'BD_exposed_coastal_area','BD_drought', 'BGD_1_River', 'BGD_1_River_detail', 'BD_international_bnd', 'BGD_1_River_1', 'BGD_7_Mauza', 'test', 'BGD_5_UpazillaAnno', 'BGD_4_new_districtAnno', 'BGD_4_new_districtAnno2']
Cld2 = ['BD_Health_Infrastructures_1', 'BD_Railway_Establishments_1', 'BGD_roads_1']

lis1 = [os.path.join(x, y) for x in P for y in Cld1]
lis2 = [os.path.join(x, y) for x in P for y in Cld2]

My_Full_Path = lis1 + lis2

pprint.pprint(My_Full_Path)
```

**output:**

```
['E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_district',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_3_old_district',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_2_division',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_all',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_5_Upazilla',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_old_district',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_6_Union_court',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_6_Union',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_exposed_coastal_area',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_drought',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River_detail',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BD_international_bnd',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_1_River_1',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_7_Mauza',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\test',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_5_UpazillaAnno',
 'E:\\GIS_DOCUMENT\\BCAS_Map\\BCAS_All.gdb\\BD_Admin\\BGD_4_new_districtAn
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: I think first element's children are in Cld1 and second ones's in Cld2 so ```zip``` is not good here

Comment: this solution is fits task description but not common sense

Comment: Yes i have buddy if it means upvoting

Answer (score 2):

use `os.path.join`

```
nez_Cld1 = [os.path.join(P[0], i) for i in Cld1] 
nez_Cld2 = [os.path.join(P[1], i) for i in Cld2]
```